# Get rid of whitespace on top of the text in div

Tags: css, html

[image: Div bounding box]

Here is a bounding box of a `div` tag as shown by Chrome Dev Tools. Both `font-size` and `line-height` are set to `100px`. `margin` and `padding` properties are set to `0`. The div element is absolutely positioned on a webpage.

How to make the text start right from the top of the bounding box? I need to get rid of white-space on top of the "S" character.

If that's impossible to get rid of white space, is there a way to calculate its height?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/zw4g1uuj/

Comment: can you post some code or fiddle?

Comment: code would be nice. is that an image or a font?

Comment: @satya thank you for looking into this. I updated the question with a fiddle.

Comment: @JaredGoertzen thank you for looking into this. I updated the question with a fiddle.

Comment: Please Check This: https://jsfiddle.net/zw4g1uuj/2/

Comment: @satya thank you for the modification. How to calculate the height based on current font size and line height?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed while taking a look at your JSFiddle that the line height might be the primary factor as to why you're seeing whitespace. At font-size 100, the bounding box of the div will fit to the text, and you centered it with lineheight 100. The issue is that when you have a div with an unbounded height (and in this case the text is what the box is sized to), you're adding yet another factor to the size of the div (lineheight) which causes white space to appear at the top when you dont want it. By decreasing the lineheight, lets say 80 in the JSFiddle, I could easily make the top white space decrease.

If you made the div bounded to maybe a fixed height of 120, then lineheighted to 120, the text would center, have even spacing on both the top and bottom. Decreasing the fixed size of the box closer to the size of the font and adjusting the lineheight can squeeze even more whitespace out of it.

This one of the more finicky pieces of CSS to work around. I've always had trouble predicting lineheight behavior so its best to experiment with this. Any CSS code from the parent containers or how you designed the element in question could interfere with it.

Not only that, the font can EASILY add whitespace because its not anything inherently wrong with the CSS, it could just be that the font has a few more pixels at the top than it does at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I need a universal solution that will work for every font and size combination.

Comment: To put it blunt, there is no way to provide a universal solution to fonts because they're all different. I don't know how rehearsed you are in CSS but if you're a veteran or even adept in it, you should know "universal solutions" don't exist-that is just one of the many pains that exist when designing in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you have to play with both your font-size and line-height till you have what you are looking for. Use this in your JSFiddle for the styles...

```
font-size: 100px;
line-height: 75px;
border: 1px solid red;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I need a universal solution that will work for every font and size combination.